# How to obtain the index of a line specific value [ a b c d] within a double matrix?

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have made a table composed of four variables[v1, v2, v3, v4], with near 26000 rows. I need to search the values of an specific line e.g. [1 1 2 2016] within the table (26000 x 4), and return the index of the line in which the search is located.

Example of what I would like to search:

```
want_1 = [1 1 3 2016];
want_2 = [1 1 5 2016];
```

And would like to obtain the number of the line in which it is located.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Does the table only contain numeric values? If so, why not use a numeric matrix instead of a table? It's more efficient and simplifies the operation you want to do

Comment: Yes, it only has numeric values. I will make it a matrix. Very newbie using matlab.. :)

Comment: May I obtain the row index separatedly of each variable, n times it shows, and then ask for the intersect values between them?

Comment: Which version of MATLAB are you using?

Comment: Kind of. I want to search for the row in which all the 4 elements occur, and return the index of the row.

To put it in a context, v1 = hour, v2 = day, v3 = month, v4 = year.
I am using some functions in which I need to specify the indexes in which the analysis will be performed - for example, from row 10000 to row 11000.
These rows represent time periods. but in order to make it easier to define the row numbers, I want to make a function in which I put in an array the values I want for [hour, day, month, year] and the function returns to me the number of the row..

Comment: I am using 2017a

Comment: 2017a means you can use Wolfie's approach. Regardless, you might want to consider using [`datetime`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html) to represent points in time, because these objects have various useful properties such as being able to easily find time durations and perform comparisons (e.g. return all values between two dates).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a matrix `M` (which you could get from `table2array(T)` on your table) you should be able to use implicit expansion* and `all` to get your result

```
srch = [1 1 3 2016]; % Row to search for
res = find( all( M == srch, 2 ) );
```

The `find` converts the logical array returned by `all` into the row numbers where it is true.

The implicit expansion here is basically the same as repeating the `srch` array for the entire height of the matrix `M` and then doing an element-wise `==` operation. The `all` then ensures that every comparison in a given row was true (i.e. a match for every element of `srch`).

<sup>*Implicit expansion relies on having MATLAB R2016b or newer... for older versions you can achieve the same using `bsxfun`.</sup>

---

Just as an exercise in alternatives, you could use `splitapply` instead to apply the `all` and `==` operators to each row in turn, this is probably slower...

```
res = find( splitapply( @(x)all(x==srch), M, (1:size(M,1)).' ) );
```

Or you could even use `rowfun`, which is a bit of a loop-in-disguise, but **would work on your table** `T` without having to first convert it to a matrix:

```
res = find( rowfun( @(varargin)all([varargin{:}]==srch), T, 'OutputFormat', 'uniform' ) );
```

Comment: @KarolB It might be worth mentioning that perhaps you don't even need the row numbers (i.e. what `find` gives), and could just use the logical index. Of course it's hard to say w/o knowing more about the problem.

Answer (score 2):

For a **matrix**, you can use [`ismember`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) with the `'rows'` option:

```
M = [1 2 3 4; 1 1 3 2016; 5 6 7 8]; % example data matrix
wanted = [1 1 3 2016]; % example wanted row
result = find(ismember(M, wanted, 'rows'));
```

This also works with a **table**, as long as the wanted row is a table (of one row) with the same variable names:

```
M = table;
M.hour = [1; 2; 3]; M.day = [4; 5; 6]; M.month = [7; 8; 9]; M.year = [10; 11; 12];
wanted = table;
wanted.hour = 2; wanted.day = 5; wanted.month = 8; wanted.year = 11;
result = find(ismember(M, wanted, 'rows'));
```

Comment: An "easier" (more automated at least) way to make the table in your edit would be `wanted = array2table( [2 5 8 11], 'VariableNames', M.Properties.VariableNames );`

Comment: Thank you so much. I was two days struggling with that (I just started working with this). 

Your support without judgement made me really happy.